# jQuery get element of class on .hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.product-list').hover(
  $('.product-list-thumbnail ').css({'opacity': "0.2;"})
);
```

On hover of an element i'm trying to change the opacity of another element. I tried using CSS, but this is the only solution I could find.

My HTML looks like:

```
<article class="wrapper">
  <div class="product-list-thumbnail "><img src="" /></div>
  <div class="product-list">Product details</div>
</article>
```

As I have a lot of these on the page. How can I target the class `.product-list-thumbnail` that's within the container my current class is in?

Thanks!

Comment: that is not the proper way to use hover...

Comment: @epascarello it's the only way I could find to be able to toggle another element above the current one on hover

Comment: hover expects a function, that is not function

Comment: You could do this with CSS `.wrapper:hover .product-list-thumbnail { opacity: 0.2; }` but the element you're changing the opacity off must be a child of the one you're hovering over.

Comment: Hey, shouldn't the class name be "product-list-thumbnail" instead of ".product-list-thumbnail" ?

Comment: @coderz haha sorry, my bad. Dot slipped in some how :p

Comment: @Martin that's the main issue in which I came to the conclusion of using jQuery `hover` after doing some research. On hover of one element, I want to change the style of the element above which isn't it's parent

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @MeMyselfAndI, it happens with all :) Hope you found your solution. There are some good looking solutions posted!

Answer (score 8):

You're not properly using method `hover`. This method expects two functions, first is called on hover and second called on blur. Also you can use `$.siblings` to find `.product-list-thumbnail`.

```
$('.product-list').hover(
  function(){
   $(this).siblings('.product-list-thumbnail').css({'opacity': "0.2"}); 
  },
  function(){
   $(this).siblings('.product-list-thumbnail').css({'opacity': "1"}) ;
  }  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a misstyping but in your html syntax there is a dot. ".product-list-thumbnail" 
Try this.

```
 <div class="product-list">Product details</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you could try and remove the period on the class to look like this `<div class="product-list-thumbnail ">` then I'd suggest a change the html code to wrap the thumbnail on the same element (better syntax) to something like

```
<div class="product-detail">
    <img src="" />
    Product detail information
</div>
```

So you can affect the element through css like this:

`.product-detail:hover img {opacity: .2}`

Answer (score 0):

fix the line  **<div class=".product-list-thumbnail">** replace with  **<div class="product-list-thumbnail">**

..And here we are ;)

```
$('.product-list').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.product-list-thumbnail').css({'opacity': '0.2'})
},function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.product-list-thumbnail').css({'opacity': '1'})
});
```